# Getting ValueError

Tags: python

```
def isArmstrong(val: int) -> bool:
    """val will be tested to see if its an Armstrong number.
    Arguments:
        val {int} -- positive integer only.
    Returns:
        bool -- true is /false isn't
    """
 
    # break the int into its respective digits
    parts = [int(_) for _ in str(val)]
 
    # begin test.
    counter = 0
    for _ in parts:
        counter += _**3
    return (counter == val)
 
 
# Driver Program
x =int(str(input()))
if isArmstrong(int(x)):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

I'm getting below error when ever enter 103 as a input

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File Main.py , line 20, in x =int(str(input())) 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `103` is the input you are sending to `int(input())`? If I feed 103 in, I don't get an error. But if I give it a *float* like `103.0`, I do get that error

Comment: `int(str(input()))` only needs to be `int(input())` inputs will always be strings.

Comment: The error message says that the string is empty. That means you're just pressing Return.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be inputting the values right, I was able to use the code and input an integer. This code is not handling any of the potential errors, you should be careful with the input and handle it right.

Also, the `_` throwaway variable is for values that one is not using. If you are using the value, you should define it.

Try to use the built-in `argparse` library to handle the input using flags, this way you can specify flags and handle incorrect inputs. I am including a snippet of how I would improve your code for reference.

```py
import argparse

def isArmstrong(val: int) -> bool:
    """
    The :param val: will be tested to see if its an Armstrong number.

    Arguments:
        val {int} -- positive integer only.
    Returns:
        bool -- true is /false isn't
    """
 
    # break the int into its respective digits
    parts = [int(i) for i in str(val)]
 
    # begin test.
    counter = 0
    for part in parts:
        counter += part**3
    return (counter == val)
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    description = 'Test if a number is an Armstrong number.'
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=description)
    parser.add_argument('val', type=int, help='The number to test.')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    if isArmstrong(args.val):
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

Output:

[image: output]